# select_on_container_copy_construction not called for std::string

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, stdstring, allocator

`select_on_container_copy_construction` in my allocator is not called for `std:::string`. It works fine when used with a `vector` tough. Why is the behavior different? Is this a bug in GCC?

I am using gcc version 5.4.0.

Code example with a minimal allocator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
class allocator {
public:
  typedef T value_type;

  using propagate_on_container_copy_assignment = std::true_type; // for consistency
  using propagate_on_container_move_assignment = std::true_type; // to avoid the pessimization
  using propagate_on_container_swap = std::true_type; // to avoid the undefined behavior

  allocator<T> select_on_container_copy_construction() const {
    throw std::bad_alloc();
  }

  T *allocate(const std::size_t n) {
    return static_cast<T *>(::operator new(n * sizeof(T)));
  }

  void deallocate(T *, const std::size_t) { }
};

template< class T1, class T2 >
bool operator==(const allocator<T1>&, const allocator<T2>&) noexcept {
  return true;
}

template< class T1, class T2 >
bool operator!=(const allocator<T1>&, const allocator<T2>&) noexcept {
  return false;
}

int main()
{
  try {
    std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, allocator<char>> s;
    auto ss = s;
  } catch (std::bad_alloc const&) {
    std::cout << "string worked\n";
  }

  try {
    std::vector<int, allocator<int>> v;
    auto vv = v;
  } catch (std::bad_alloc const&) {
    std::cout << "vector worked\n";
  }
}
```

The program should print both "string worked" and "vector worked", but it only prints the latter.

Comment: the code does not even compile on my machine with -std=c++17

Comment: @Artyer: Does not change the behavior, but I added the operators.

Comment: @CSPei: What error do you get?

Comment: Tons of errros, including the missing operator== and !=

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Works fine on `gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 18.0.4)` and `gcc version 8.2.0 (Ubuntu 18.0.4)` with glibc 7. (As in "COPY THROW!!!" is printed if i get rid of `auto vv = v;`, and if I get rid of `auto ss = s;`). What version of gcc are you using?

Comment: usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.h:3097:63: error: no class template named ‘rebind’ in ‘class Allocator<char>’
       typedef typename _Alloc::template rebind<_CharT>::other _CharT_alloc_type;

Comment: gcc 8.2.1 is what I am using. RH

Comment: works for me https://ideone.com/vRVviK ,have you checked your libraries std::string implementation to see if std::allocator_triats::select_on_container_copy_construction is used?

Comment: @AndreasPasternak You might want to use gdb and break `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, allocator<char>>::basic_string(const basic_string&)` to see why it bypasses `select_on_container_copy_construction`

Comment: Thanks, everyone for the help. it is actually a compiler bug (https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2402) as I posted in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in libstdc++ that was resolved in the 6.1 release by [this PR](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/b7aaabf0829d9d3633e7e7a821885173aa0849c0).

The specific relevant change was from:

```
basic_string(const basic_string& __str)
: _M_dataplus(_M_local_data(), __str._M_get_allocator()) // TODO A traits
```

to:

```
basic_string(const basic_string& __str)
: _M_dataplus(_M_local_data(),
    _Alloc_traits::_S_select_on_copy(__str._M_get_allocator()))
```

I'm not sure if there was an open bug report. I can't find one and the commit message doesn't reference one.